# Send Push message with Amazon Web Service

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

i have configured an app in AWS SNS portal , i want to send device token to AWS SNS service ,
 i donwloaded the framework form AWS site, and i managed to find some sample codes to integarte in to my ios App

```
 AmazonSNSClient *snsClient = [[AmazonSNSClient alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"myAccessKey" withSecretKey:@"mySecretKey"];


SNSCreatePlatformEndpointRequest *endpointRequest = [SNSCreatePlatformEndpointRequest new];
endpointRequest.token = [self deviceTokenAsString:newDeviceToken];
endpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = @"myAppARN";
[snsClient createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest];
```

but unfortunatly that framework doesnt contains these classes , is thr any framework for me to integrate, does anyone got a tutorial to this

Answer (score 0):

- download AWS sdk and in that folder find messageboard.h and messageboard.m file and put both file in that project which you work now.
- then which class use you want to SNS function in .m file and appdelegate.m file write this line. #import "MessageBoard.h"

now when you want to send device token to AWS SNS service there write some code:

```
[[MessageBoard instance] createApplicationEndpoint:replace here user name which you want to send there];
```

now open messageboard.h file and go createApplicationEndpoint method.

in this method enter your device token.

```
 endpointARN = endpointResponse.endpointArn;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:endpointARN forKey:@"DEVICE_ENDPOINT"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: i cannot access createApplicationEndpoint method in SDK ,which SDK did  u use ??

Comment: @Hendrik Patel , i downloaded , SDK v1 , any reason that methods are not available in V2 ??

Comment: http://ge.tt/6I5pLBr1/v/0?c open this link and download demo code for sns and open AWS SDK V1 and put some needed framework in your project.

Comment: @Mr.G i don't know why this method are not available in V2.